# How to send token to a remote server with GET method request?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android studio. I have a problem how can i send token id to a remote server with GET method request to get information, because i must be authenticated to get those information. 
Below the GET method and the error msg, help please ! [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xm9W.png)error msg [GET method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fqm4.png)

Comment: First you need to get token from server. That usually goes by user login/sign up when token is generated.

Comment: okay, and after that how i implemented ?

Comment: You need to provide token inside `header` I think there are some examples how to do that. Like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000212/how-to-send-authorization-header-in-android-using-volley-library
Where ACESS_TOKEN is your token from server.

Comment: so i provide token inside header and put it inside GET method like the example ?

Comment: Did you try okHttp3? it's an awesome library

Answer (score 1):

You can use the support of [Retrofit Library](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Firstly, in your gradle, add this line to download.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

Secondly, Select the type of RequestBody in @Body

```
Gson: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson
Jackson: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson
Moshi: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi
Protobuf: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf
Wire: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-wire
Simple XML: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml
Scalars (primitives, boxed, and String): com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars
```

then add it in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Thirdly, Create a interface class to use @GET method or others, for example:

```
public interface CallMethodService {
        @GET("search")
        Call<ResponseModel>  getResponseModel();
    }
```

Lastly, In your MainActivity:

create a Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("base server link")
                        .addConverterFactory(RequestBody type)
                        .build();
```

for example:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

then call to get data:

```
 retrofit.create(CallMethodService.class).getResponseModel()
            .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
                   //get data
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GifResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                   // No internet
                }
            });
```

Comment: i got this msg "Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson" any help ?

Comment: ok, you add the version after  com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0

Comment: read more : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381710/how-to-call-simple-get-method-using-retrofit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

You can try with OkHttp3.
Add this to your GRADLE:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

Create a class and extends it from `AsyncTask`
Then call it from `onCreate` method

```
new DataToServer().execute();
```

`DataToServer` class implementation

```
private class DataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        GetDataFromUrl getData = new GetDataFromUrl();
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = getData.run(URL_of_your_server);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //you got the server response on the result variable

    }

}
```

And this is the implementation of OkHttp

```
 private class GetDataFromUrl {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String run(String url) throws IOException {

            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .build();


            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } finally {
                if (response != null) {
                    response.close();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out , it was this one :

@Override

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("x-access-token", TokenHandler.getToken());
    return headers;
}
```