# HTTP GET in android Kotlin

Tags: android, http, kotlin, get, request

I am programming in android studio. I have a button, that send a http request. When i click the button, my app crash!

There's my code

MainActivity.kt

```java
package com.example.messager

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.net.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun onclick(v:View){
        URL ("https://google.com/").readText()
    }
}
```

please, help me! I really want to send get http request

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the domain https://google.com/

```
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute({
        val data = URL("https://google.com/").readText()
        simpleTextView.post { simpleTextView.text = data }
    })
```

You can contact the resource and take the information you need from it

Comment: You need to make such requests in a separate thread, so as not to stop the program for a certain action, the user may think that the program does not respond, if you use one thread, the program may also crash due to the use of one thread

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way to open a URL would be to open chrome browser from your Android app via `Intents`. Add the following line of code in your onClick method.

```
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com") 
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
startActivity(intent)
```

But if you want to send a GET request to an endpoint, I would suggest you use a Network Client. For example: [Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385117/6845131) or Volley.

Example for sending a GET request using Volley:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://www.google.com"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
            textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple)